# stat st_mode returns 0600 for/proc/1/task/1/fd/4

Tags: c, dart, stat

I'm working on a bug in dart that causes it to abort when it reads a directory listing including the /proc dir on linux.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43176

../../runtime/bin/directory_linux.cc: 204: error: Unexpected st_mode: 384

I'm trying to understand the return from the stat command:

```
/proc/1/task/1/fd/4
st_mode 384 (octal 0600)
ino 11676 uid 0 gid 0 4
```

If I understand correctly the top bits should indicate the file type.

How should I correctly interpret the file type in this case?

Comment: Do you mean `stat` command or C function? If you mean the `stat` function then just read the [stat man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). It describes how to parse the `st_mode` bits. If that is not it then please provide clearer details in your question about the actual issue.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html

Comment: @barmar it isnt on linux ..

Comment: I just tried `stat .bashrc` and it said `Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)`

Comment: It seems that `stat(1)` doesn't show the bits that correspond to the device type. `stat /dev/tty` says `Access: (0666/crw-rw-rw-)`

Comment: @Barmar kernel source says regular file is `0100000`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d6f9469a03d832dcd17041ed67774ffb5f3e73b3/include/uapi/linux/stat.h#L12